# Testcafe Selector does not get element in React Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using testcafe to drive a website. I created a page model and I can click on the buttons I already created.

However, my page uses React to create a Modal dialog that is visible only after I click a button. I can get the element using the browser console with `document.querySelectorAll('.modal-footer > button')[1]`.

So in my page model I used `Selector('.modal-footer > button').nth(1);` and I also tried creating a selector using the syntax in [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/creating-selectors.html).
In both cases, testcafe is not able to find the element, and I ended up getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of null` error.

Here's my code:

```
// page model
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export class PageModel {
  constructor () {
    ... // a bunch of buttons
    this.modalButton = Selector('.modal-footer > button').nth(1);
  }
}
```

and my test

```
// test script
import { PageModel } from 'page_model'

const pagemodel = new PageModel();

fixture ...

test('My Test', async t => {
  await t.click(pagemodel.abutton);
  await t.click(pagemodel.openDialog); // the modal dialog opens

  await t.click(pagemodel.modalButton) // <-- Here's where I get the error
});
```

Using an If statement that only clicks on the button if the button is visible (`if (modalButton.exists)`), seems to work. But I still get the error when that button disappears after I click.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with a try-catch block. I think there are some race conditions in the browser that were causing the test to fail.

```
const max_retries = 3
let count = 0;
  while (count < max_retries) {
    try {
      await t
        .click(pagemodel.modalButton);
      break;
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error('An error occurred, trying again...');
      count++;
      if (count === retries) {
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The cause of the error you provided is unclear. I would like to research it deeper.
However. it's difficult to determine the cause of the issue without a sample. Please create a separate issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository using the following form https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md. 
I would appreciate it if you create a sample example which demonstrate the issue and share it.